# How does StringBuilder.delete interpret the arguments?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I have a buffering method for the `telnet` text communication. Aside from standard letters, this communication has some funny control characters. One of them is character DELETE with `8` integer value.

I want to implement this value - it would really help me using the program from telnet since currently I need to retype whole command if I press one character wrong.

So I made a check function that is called every time character is received:

```
public boolean newChar(char current, StringBuilder all) {
    //Debug info
    switch (current) {
        case 13 : Log.debug("Character '\\r' [13]");break;   
        case 10 : Log.debug("Character '\\n' [10]");break;  
        case 8 : Log.debug("Character DELETE [8]");break;  
        default:Log.debug("Character '"+current+"' ["+(int)current+"]"); 
    }

    //Delete character
    if(current==8) {
          int length = all.length();
          if(length>1) {
            ///THIS DOES NOT WORK
            //all.delete(length-2, length-1);
            ///WHILE FOLLOWING WORKS WELL
            all.deleteCharAt(length-1);
            all.deleteCharAt(length-2);
            Log.debug("Deleted one character from buffer. Current buffer:\n    "+all);
          }
          else
            all.deleteCharAt(length-1);
    }
    //Ignore newlines
    else if(current=='\r'||current=='\n') {
          all.deleteCharAt(all.length()-1);
    }
    //Return true if current character is newline
    //True return value means that the buffer now contains whole message...
    return current=='\n';
}
```

If delete character is received, it should be deleted as well as the character right before it. I assumed the [`delete(int start, int end)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#delete%28int,%20int%29) should suit that purpose.

```
int length = builder.length();
builder.delete(length-2, length-1);
```

This would, however, delete 2 characters **and** the *delete* character - 3 characters all together:

```
Character '6' [54]
Character '6' [54]
Character '6' [54]
Character DELETE [8]
Deleted one character from buffer. Current buffer:
    6
```

I also tried `builder.delete(length-1, length);`, though it makes no sense. Id didn't delete anything I could see. (I guess it deleted the delete character and then silently failed).
Funny enough, this works fine for me:

```
builder.deleteCharAt(length-1);
builder.deleteCharAt(length-2);
```

Could anyone explain why is this happening?

Comment: start is inclusive, end is exclusive. How do you manage those in order to delete 3 characters?

Comment: Oh but that's incredibly confusing... I only guessed that 3 characters were deleted. The `DELETE` character is invisible in the output of course.

Comment: I think in [ASCII it's called BS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ASCII_Code_Chart-Quick_ref_card.jpg), not DELETE (BS stands for Backspace)

Comment: Also by default telnet uses LINEMODE - so all backspaces are processed on client side, why do you have to deal with them on server?

Comment: My telnet (Windows telnet) does not use linemode by default. And thanks for telling me the name of the character - I just named it DELETE when I was using it. I have never read any docs about how that telnet actually works.